# Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client while accessing hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to hadoop. I have done single node hadoop setup of version 2.7.5 .I am able to access hadoop from terminal but when I am trying to access it from java I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1437)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1455)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
at com.learning.hadoop.WordCountJob.main(WordCountJob.java:72)
```

Here is maven dependency I have used in my project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Code I am using to access hdfs:

```
        String file_path = "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/input/inputFile";
        URI uri=URI.create(file_path);
        Path path=new Path (uri);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        //Get the filesystem - HDFS 

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf); //Getting exception here
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `hadoop-core` version to `2.7.5` to use updated version of hadoop.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```